# Batch Update products

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I'm doing a orders program and I have a binary search tree for products, item contain product name, stock quantity, order quantity, and price. When I creeate an order, the order quantity in the selected item is increased according to the order.

I am required to create a function, called batchUpdate, which goes goes through the tree and substracts the stock quantity by the order quantity for each item, and obviously setting the order quantity to 0 again. The order quantity is being updated when a new order is created, but for some reason nothing is happening. here are a few snippets:

```
void BatchUpdate(PTree * pt) //PTree is a typedef, the tree
{
    if (PTreeIsEmpty(pt))
        puts("Nothing to update!");
    else
    {
        puts("test"); //just for debug, it is still being displayed
        TraverseP(pt,MinusStock); //Traverses the tree, and applies function 
                                  //MinusStock to each item in the node
    }
}

void MinusStock(Prdct C) //Prdct is a typedef of struct containing details
{
    C.StockQ = C.StockQ - C.OrderQ;
    C.OrderQ = 0;

}

void TraverseP(const PTree * ptree, void (* pfun)(Prdct item))
{
    if (ptree != NULL)
        InOrderP(ptree->root,pfun);
}

static void InOrderP(const PNode * root, void (* pfun)(Prdct item))
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        (*pfun)(root->item);
        InOrderP(root->left, pfun);
        InOrderP(root->right, pfun);
    }
}
```

no error is being given, it just ignores the traverse, and puts("test") is being displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MinusStock(Prdct C) //Prdct is a typedef of struct containing details
{
    C.StockQ = C.StockQ - C.OrderQ;
    C.OrderQ = 0;

}
```

This is the problem, you are taking it **by value**, this means that any changes are **NOT affecting the tree elements**, since you are **operating on a copy** of the data which is **destroyed after this function terminates**.

This can be fixed by making the below change.

```
void MinusStock(Prdct* C){
                     ^
```

This means you take the product struct **as a pointer** and thus any changes to it are **persistant**.

To do this you also need to change both how you call, `(*pfun)(&root->item);` and how you access the variable, `C->OrderQ = 0;`, and how you define the function pointer, `void (* pfun)(Prdct* item)`.

Thank you @MathewHall for correctly pointing out that this is a C question.

To **summarise**, the **traverse IS happening**, but it is not changing the tree, instead it is **creating copies of each element** before it operates on them, leaving the tree as-is.

Comment: The question is tagged `C`, not `C++` - I guess these will be structs, not objects so the change will need to be to change the arguments to `pfun` and `MinusStock` pointers, rather than references.

Comment: I'll give it a try, the traverse and in order functions worked as they are for other functions such as saving to a binary file, and searching..guess I'll have a make a copy and alter them slightly. thanks

Comment: @PatrickBuhagiar hope the copy is only for testing, remember the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). You shouldnt need to make a copy.

Comment: @PatrickBuhagiar the reason that save and search do not suffer from this issue is because they do not modify the tree.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C to be honest, this is my first program actually, I'll try to find the alternative to copying

Comment: @PatrickBuhagiar in that case you might want to read up on [pointers](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=pointers+C&aq=f&oq=pointers+C&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j0l3j60.4481&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), there is a lot more to them when compared to using simple variables.

Comment: Ok solved it, maybe kinda unprofessional I think:
I kept everything the same in the functions, but instead of the value 'C.StockQ' for example, I did: 
'(SeekItemP(&C,&prdct)).child->item.StockQ'

The SeekItem finds the struct C in the actual tree prdcr by traversing and comparing each node.